# How can I get the latest child's key in firebase db? -js

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with this data structure:

[image]

How can I get the Input's latest child's name, like 3 or 120?

this is my code:

```
const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
const inputRef = databaseRef.child("Input");
inputRef.orderByChild("dataAdded").limitToLast(lastInputs).once('value', snap => {
    console.log(snap.key);
  });
```

The problem is that, when I run the program, it returns 'Input'.

Answer (score 0):

If by "latest", you mean "most recent", then you will have to store a timestamp along with the data you've written for the child, then query for the data you're looking for using that timestamp value.  Since Realtime Database only performs ascending sorted queries, you might actually want to store the negative value of a timestamp to make sure the newest values show up first in an [ordered query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).